# Magento2: Edit product from products grid

Tags: magento2

Does anyone have any proven, free solution so that I can edit the product from the product list?
I need a quick edit of the short description after clicking on the product with the tinymce editor. Some solution?

I want quick edit from grid this both column. [image]

But short description quick edit require tinymce editor. Any solution? M2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

If you check here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-wysiwyg.html

You will read that it is a form component - not a ui grid component

So the short answer is no - not without some serious modification